# Convert and show imperial to metric measurement in Yii2

Tags: yii2, measure

Is there some way in Yii2 to make correctly the conversion between inches and mm (imperial and metric)?

I would like to save the value on database in metric measurement and show the value in imperial.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `afterFind()` method in your Model to convert values when the table is called and `beforeSave()` method to convert to metric system to store the data.

You can try something like this in your Model:

```
public function afterFind()
{
    parent::afterFind();
    $this->data = $this->data * 0.0393701;
}

public function beforeSave()
{
    parent::beforeSave();
    $this->data = $this->data * 25.4;
}
```

And you can also implement the answer of @D.R in your model with the same mechanism

Comment: Yes, of course. I did not remember `Yii2` methods :)

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use this Library to convert any unit.

https://packagist.org/packages/php-units-of-measure/php-units-of-measure

Example:

```
use PhpUnitsOfMeasure\PhysicalQuantity\Length;

$l = new Length($val, 'inches');
echo $l->toUnit('mm');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your correctly, that you could simply use such functions.

```
function mmToIn ($val) {
  return $val * 0.0393701
}

function inToMm ($val) {
  return $val * 25.4
}
```